# Relative Date Item in Power Pivot GETPIVOT DATA excel function

Tags: date, excel-formula, powerbi, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am using a GETPIVOTDATA function in Excel to source data from a pivot table generated by a Power BI query (everything was originally only in excel, the file got too large, so i stored the main tables in PBI but kept the reports in excel for mgmt's sake).

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].["&$A$100&"]",'PIVOT Table_test'!$A$126,"[Master].[field1]","[Master].[field1].&["&C$26&"]","[Master].[AsofDate]","[Master].[AsofDate].&[2022-04-30T00:00:00]")
```

However, I want to make the GETPIVOTDATA function as dynamic as possible to prevent having too many hardcoded fields/items for each table that fields the charts we look at. However, when i reference the pivot table, the '[Asof]' field populates the static item as "...&[2022-04-30T00:00:00]")...

I have been trying to change that to reference a header row that contains a Short Date value (4/30/2022) like &["&$B&1"&"]")... but i keep getting #ref errors, every other field accepts the "&&" method, and when i leave the hardcoded timestamp in the formula, it populates.

So it has to be that reference but i do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have also tried changing the format of both the header row in Excel and the field within PBI but to no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Found the answer on another site. The solution in the item brackets is to write the following:
"&TEXT($A22,"yyyy-mm-dd""T00:00:00""")&"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another site. The solution in the item brackets is to write the following:

```
["&TEXT($A22,"yyyy-mm-dd""T00:00:00""")&"]
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the original site?  It might help future coders out.